# How use drop-down filters in Altair and redraw plot on selection

Tags: pandas, altair

I have some long-form data in a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
    region  result  year    variable    value
0   County Durham   North East  2014    admissions_total    2240
1   Darlington  North East  2014    admissions_total    283
2   Gateshead   North East  2014    admissions_total    1229
3   Hartlepool  North East  2014    admissions_total    484
4   Middlesbrough   North East  2014    admissions_total    422
... ... ... ... ... ...
5539    Somerset    South West  2019    adm_per_female  1800
5540    South Gloucestershire   South West  2019    adm_per_female  2663
5541    Swindon South West  2019    adm_per_female  1784
5542    Torbay  South West  2019    adm_per_female  2659
5543    Wiltshire   South West  2019    adm_per_female  1671
```

I want to add two filters: one for result and another for the value column.

My code to do first is:

```
result_selector = alt.binding_select(options=
list
(melted_df[
'result'
].unique()))
result_dropdown = alt.selection_single(fields=[
'result'
], bind=result_selector, name=
'result_filter'
)

# Create a base chart

base_chart = alt.Chart(melted_df).mark_line().encode(
    y=
'value:Q'
,
    x=
'year:O'
,
    color=
'region:N'
,
    tooltip=[
'region'
, 
'year'
, 
'value'
]
).properties(width=400)

# Apply result selection to the base chart

filtered_chart = base_chart.transform_filter(
    result_dropdown
)

# Create a full chart with selection and filtered_chart layers

full_chart = (base_chart + filtered_chart).add_selection(result_dropdown)

# Display the full chart

full_chart
```

The aim of the result filter was to filter out some much data into one display.

The other thing I can't work out is how to redraw the chart with every selection. The chart updates but it layers up.

The other thing is why there is the zig-zag pattern when I just want to show a rising trend over years.

[image]